# How to customise select box in angular 8?

Tags: html, css, angular8

I am using angular 8 with HTML5 and SCSS.

I need to customize select in the following manner as shown in the image below:

[image]

There will be two values to the left of the select option and two values to the right.
And there should be a search box using which the options can be filtered base on any four values present in the option.

All the values in the selection are dynamic values.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! for this purpose you need some third party plugins like https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-multiselect-dropdown

Comment: It is not multi select. I am only selecting a single object with multiple related value(like name,age,dob). Anyway thanks for the suggestion. I found an external package called **Primeng** (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown). It worked like magic.

Comment: Glad you solved it yourself :) Cheers